# How to retrieve data via http request in my case

Tags: angularjs, http, rest

I am trying to use `http` `GET` to retrieve my data.

in my js code

```
$http({
        url: "test.com/api/?title=1",
        method: "GET",
    }).success(function(data) {
        $scope.title = data; //I have data
        var name = $scope.title[0].name;

        $http({
            url: name + "?name=name",
            method: "GET",
        }).success(function(name) {
            console.log(name) //no response at all.
        })
        $scope.initTree();

    }).error(function(data) {

    });
```

so basically I have 1 `http` requrest wrapped in another `http` request. I can't seem to get the second request data. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks!

Comment: I bet the nested `$http` request is failing. Check your Network tab in  dev tools and make sure there is a valid response coming back from that request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [@Marc Kline](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2096726/marc-kline) said, the only problem that can happend is that your second `$http` is failing, you can just add the `.error` callback like you've done on the first and log the error in the console :

```
$http({
    url: name + "?name=name",
    method: "GET",
}).success(function(name) {
    console.log(name) //no response at all.
}).error(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```